# How do I iterate over collections in a database in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Is it possible to iterate over collections in mongoengine. I have collections named log_XXX and I'd like to find all of them.

Comment: have you tried http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.collection_names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoengine is built on top of PyMongo, so you can do everything you can do in PyMongo.

For example,

```
class Example(Document):
    pass

db = Example._get_db()
for collection_name in db.collection_names():
    print collection_name
```